# Convert an image from a file to a ByteBuffer.

Tags: android

I need to convert an image contained in a file to a `ByteBuffer`.

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "wakaicon.png");

try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {               
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {              
        Log.e("DEBUG", "[Picture Not Found]");
    }
} /* Exception handling */
```

Comment: @Mike OK, i have found the solution :
file -> Bitmap -> byteArray 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
 byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
         for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); ++i) {
             for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); ++j)                
                 pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((bitmap.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7);
             }
         }

Comment: If you have found the answer to your own question then be sure to post it as an answer, not a comment, and mark it as accepted so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: @MCeley I didn't answer else after 4 hours !!
The new problem that the picture is so big to handle them pixel by pixel :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution : file -> Bitmap -> byteArray

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()]; 
for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); ++i) { 
for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); ++j) 
pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((bitmap.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7); } 
}
```

Comment: 1 byte per pixel, really ?